# Разграничение прав доступа в Minio

Tags: minio

Необходимо разграничить права для пользователей в хранилке на Minio, чтоб каждый пользователь видел лишь те файлы,которые он загрузил.

Я хотел сделать это с помощью Python-фреймворка Django, но предоставляет ли это сам Minio?
Если нет, то какие есть альтернативы?
Насчет Ceph и OpenStack Swift тоже хотелось бы узнать позволяют ли они разделять права.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пользователями управляет приложение, то и их права на этом уровне вроде смотрятся лучше.

Все эти s3-штуки (minio, ceph) задуманы, как кластер с >=3 инстансами.
Заводить под каждое приложение кластер -- дороговато.
Соответственно пользователями кластера s3 будут скорее приложения.

Альтернативы можно смотреть и по другим критериям. Например ceph можно монтировать, а не только через s3 ходить. Я использую Minio-s3 и ceph-монтированную, думаю попробовать ceph-s3.

Comment: Хирьянов? Это вы? Тот самый Хирьянов из МФТИ, чьи курсы по алгоритмам я смотрю?

Comment: А, нет, того звали Тимофей Хирьянов

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Это вообще мой первый вопрос на Stackoverflow и я не думал, что так быстро ответят.
Наверно все таки мне лучше права сделать на уровне приложения, в моем случае на уровне Django, чем пытаться искать встроенные возможности на Minio

Comment: можно еще имена файлам в хранилище давать по хэшу от содержимого (Контентно-адресуемое хранилище данных); и смотреть, чтоб s3 наружу особо не светился.